# Huge amout data analysis

Tags: c++, algorithm, bigdata

Say we have about `1e10` lines of log file everyday, each one contains: an ID number(integer below 15 digits length), a login time, and a logout time. Some ID may login and logout several times.

**Question 1**:

How to count the total number of ID that have logged in?(We should not count each ID twice or more)

I tried to use a hashtable here, but I found the memory we should obtained may be so large.

---

**Question 2**:

Calculate the time when the population of online users are largest.

I think we may split the time of a day into 86400 seconds, then for each line of log file, add 1 to each seconds in the online interval. Or maybe I can sort the log file by login time?

Comment: Have you thought about using a database?

Comment: @aidan We may not use a database here, it a interview question

Comment: So... let's just say you have ten bytes per line, where do you have that 1TB file stored?

Comment: @zgnilec So small as 250MB? How do get that number?

Comment: @carlosdc In the hard disk of server PC.

Comment: Deleted. Was thinkind u got 10000000 lines (1e7). My bad.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin - Your question is a lie. 1^11 is 100 000 000 000 i.e. every body on this planet is contributing at least one line to your log file.

Comment: @EdHeal I am so sorry, 1^10 may not be a lie in some sites in this planet.

Comment: Assuming a line of log is 5 chars this number represents 200GB of data per day. In a few days that adds up to tera bytes.

Comment: @EdHeal But it is a truth.

Comment: No it is not - lets assume that you log every reply sent to the browser. A conservative estimate this is going to be one K. i.e. 1000 * 10^11 - i.e. 10 ^ 13 bytes - 10 000 000 000 000 - 10 tera bytes over the internet from one machine?!

Comment: @jason.foo Are you kidding?

Comment: @EdHeal Sorry for my poor knowledge on site architecture.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin - BTW it works out at 120 mega bytes per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use a [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) to store intervals of consecutive ids. 
   Scan the logs for all the login events.
   To insert an id, first search a segment containing the id: if it exists, the id is a duplicate. If it doesn't search the segments which are right after or before the id. If they exist, remove them and merge the new id as needed, and insert the new segment. If they don't exist, insert the id as a segment of 1 element.

   Once all ids have been inserted, count their number by summing the cardinals of all the segments in the tree.
2. assuming that:

   - a given id may be logged in only once at any given time,
   - events are stored in chronological order (that's what logs are normally)

   Scan the log and keep a counter `c` of the  number of currently logged in users, as well as the max number `m`  found, and the associated time `t`. For each log in, increment `c`, and for each log out decrement it. At each step  update `m` and `t` if `m` is lower than `c`.

Answer (score 6):

you can do that in a *nix shell.

1. `cut -f1 logname.log | sort | uniq | wc -l`
2. `cut -f2 logname.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -r`

Comment: Your answer on question 2 may not neet my need.I want to get the time when online people are the most

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, forget C++ and use *nix tools.  Assuming the log file is space delimited, then the number of unique logins in a given log is computed by:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' foo.log | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Gnu sort, will happily sort files larger than memory.  Here's what each piece is doing:

- *awk* is extracting the first space-delimited column (the ID number).
- *sort* is sorting those ID numbers, because *uniq* needs sorted input.
- *uniq* is returning only uniq numbers.
- *wc* prints the number of lines, which will be the number of uniq numbers.

Comment: What about the time efficiency? Is this the fastest way?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin - It's by far the fastest for the programmer, and is most likely fast enough for the computer.  I wouldn't burn X hours of expensive developer time when a few minutes of shell script will do job.

Comment: Your answer on question 2 may not neet my need.I want to get the time when online people are the most.

Comment: @prehistoric, I see.  I misread the question.  I'll delete that part.

Answer (score 1):

For question 2 to make sense: you probably have to log 2 things: user logs in and user logs out. Two different activities along with the user id. If this list is sorted by the time in which the activity (either log in or log out was done). You just scan with a counter called currentusers: add 1 for each log in and -1 for each log out. The maximum that number (current users) reaches is the value you're interested in, you will probably be interested also in tracking at what time it occurred..

Answer (score 0):

For 1, you can try working with fragments of the file at a time that are small enough to fit into memory.
i.e. instead of

```
countUnique([1, 2, ... 1000000])
```

try

```
countUnique([1, 2, ... 1000]) + 
countUnique([1001, 1002, ... 2000]) + 
countUnique([2001, 2002, ...]) + ... + countUnique([999000, 999001, ... 1000000])
```

2 is a bit more tricky. Partitioning the work into manageable intervals (a second, as you suggested) is a good idea. For each second, find the number of people logged in during taht second by using the following check (pseudocode):

```
def loggedIn(loginTime, logoutTime, currentTimeInterval):
    return user is logged in during currentTimeInterval
```

Apply loggedIn to all 86400 seconds, and then maximize the list of 86400 user counts to find the time that the population of online users is the largest.

Comment: For the second problem it would be better as the OP says: allocate an array of 86400 integers and loop through the file just once.

Comment: be careful, an id unique in one fragment may appear in others, so you need to merge them by doing successive result set differences.